# Corona SDK Vs. Adobe Air

Tags: air, game-physics, coronasdk

I'm developing apps for iOS using ObjectiveC, And want now to create games for multiple platform.
I've checked out Corona SDK (even wrote some code) and it looks nice, Yesterday I heard that Adobe AIR is very mature now and want to check it out before I start and write even a single line of code. 
I can't decide which framework to get into : Corona SDK or Adobe AIR and need your help.

I read a lot of blogs on this issue but none of them can help me deciding... What I need is the simplest way to build 2D game with physics, levels etc. I don't want to have the need to program extensions myself to support some features on iOS or on Android. On the way I've also got into Cocos2D but that is far then my needs (It's too native and relatively complex then Corona)

The main market I'm planning to get into is iOS and Android (other supports is just nice to have). Can anyone who had experience using both platforms explain the pros and cons on each one. At least help me understand the future support devices, How hard is it to really code once and then just compile to each os (heard that on AIR it could take a serious effort sometimes but don't really know if that's true or why...), Developing environment or any other issues I cannot think of.

Thanks!

Comment: *I read a lot of blogs on this issue but none of them can help me deciding* - why don't you just write a simple game in both and compare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a matter of personal preference. However, having some experience in game programming, I found CoronaSDK very straightforward and easy to use. I like Lua very much, so it was pure pleasure to write apps in  it, but I can imagine someone thrown back by the language.

There's however one important factor that isn't quite discussable: Corona is designed to make games in it. Everything, from API to Simulator, is tailored to simplify creation of *games*. I'm not quite sure that's the case with AIR, which is more general. It can be a + if you want to create something other than the games too, or - if you just want to develop a simple game.

It also has nice built-in physics.